# jQuery not recoqnizing form and page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form that needs to be submitted and the data sent to mysql with Ajax and jQuery, however when clicking submit, the page refreshes and the jQuery code is not running.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname" required=""></br>
        <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname" required=""></br>
        <input type="text" id="signup_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required=""></br>
        <select id="gender" class="form-control">
            <option>Select Gender</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select></br>
        <input type="password" id="signup_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <input type="submit" id="signup_button" name="signup_button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign up">
    </form>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()){
        $("#signup_button").click(function() {
            var firstname = $("input#firstname").val();
            var lastname = $("input#lastname").val();
            var email = $("input#signup_email").val();
            var gender = $("select#gender").val();
            var password = $("input#signup_password").val();

            var datastring = 'new=yes'+'&firstname='+firstname+'&lastname='+lastname'&email='+email+'&gender='+gender+'&password='+password;

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST";
                url:"api/signup.php";
                data: datastring;
                cache: true;
                success: function(html) {
                    $.("#alert_succes_congrats").css('display', '');
                }
            }) 
            return false;
        })
    }
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't listen for form submission with click events - listen for submit events on the form instead. Otherwise, if I submit your form by pressing enter in a text field, I bypass your JS. When you say the JS is not running, how have you clarified this? Did you put some alerts in various places to check if it's running? Errors in the console? etc

Comment: `$('form').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // send with AJAX });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code has lot of syntax error:

```
$(function()){
```

Should be

```
$(function(){
```

Plus the ajax members should be separated by comma and not semi-colon, there was issue in string concatenation as well. Next time this happens, please check the browser console for any javascript issues.

This should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#signup_button").click(function() {
        var firstname = $("input#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("input#lastname").val();
        var email = $("input#signup_email").val();
        var gender = $("select#gender").val();
        var password = $("input#signup_password").val();

        var datastring = 'new=yes'+'&firstname='+firstname+'&lastname='+lastname+'&email='+email+'&gender='+gender+'&password='+password;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"api/signup.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#alert_succes_congrats").css('display', '');
            }
        }); 
    return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to solve your problem:

**1st option:**

Change

```
<input type="submit" id="signup_button" name="signup_button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign up">
```

To

```
<input type="button" id="signup_button" name="signup_button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign up">
```

So the button will not trigger a form submit.

**2nd option:**

Put an event.preventDefault at your click handler.

```
$("#signup_button").click(function(event) {
    /* Your stuff */
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

So it will not trigger browser default action to form submit button.

Comment: If I am using option 1, nothing happens, so it is not triggering my JS. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange. It should trigger your JS, since your JS is binding an handler to `#signup_button` **click** event, not to your form submit event.

Comment: Well, you can try it on rt.kthorndahl.com It is really strange to me, since I have used a lot of times, where it worked perfectly..

Comment: My console shows me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` at line 18 in your HTML.

Comment: Line 18: `$(function()){`

It should be `$(function(){`.

Comment: Found it. Not it is saying that my variable datastring was unepected